# Returning data which contains data owned by function

Tags: rust

I want to have a `DataAllocator` that can return data with lifetime `'r`, so I can pass it to `something` and still be able to return the value allocated inside `something`:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct Data<'a, T>{
    a: &'a [T]
}

impl<'a, T> Data<'a, T> {
    pub fn new() -> Data<'a, T> {
        todo!()
    }
    
    fn iter(&'a self) -> Iter<'a, T> {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub struct Iter<'a, T> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a T>
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub trait DataAllocator<'s, 'r, T> {
    fn allocate(&'s self) -> Box<dyn AsRef<[T]> + 'r>;
}

impl<'s, 'r, T> DataAllocator<'s, 'r, T> for Data<'r, T> {
    fn allocate(&'s self) -> Box<dyn AsRef<[T]> + 'r> {
        todo!()
    }
}

fn do_something<'a, 'b, T>(data_allocator: &'a dyn DataAllocator<'a, 'b, T>) -> Data<'b, T> {
    let buffer = data_allocator.allocate();
    let data = Data{a: (*buffer).as_ref()};
    for e in data.iter(){}
    data
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2a3e0d0cdea86238413af25dddd04e19

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local data `*buffer`
  --> src/lib.rs:42:5
   |
40 |     let data = Data{a: (*buffer).as_ref()};
   |                        ------------------ `*buffer` is borrowed here
41 |     for e in data.iter(){}
42 |     data
   |     ^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

The problem is that if I try to iterate over `data`, then it complains that I'm trying to return something that is borrowed by the `.iter()` function. I think it might have to do with me saying that `.iter()` borrows the `Data` for the lifetime `'b`, which is the entire lifetime of the allocated data. What can I do in this case?

Comment: If you remove the iteration, you still get exactly the same error.

Comment: If you're only interesting in returning either slices or `Vec`s, might consider using [`Cow<'r, [T]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) instead of `Box<AsRef>`?

Answer (score 4):

I think the confusion is getting `.as_ref()` on a `dyn AsRef<[T]> + 'r` returns a reference tied to itself, not to the `'r` lifetime. So the reference you get from `(*buffer).as_ref()` is derived from `buffer`, which of course goes out of scope.

Its hard to say what you should do about it though, since the `todo!()`s obscure how you were planning to accomplish this. But based on what I see, I would probably expect the `allocate()` to return a `&'r [T]`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ad3a1ed66412fefd247f05595be1c11f).

Comment: now I get it. The problem with your solution is that it only lets me return references. What if I want to really allocate something that lives by itself? For example, I could use `TypedArena` for allocating a true slice, but I could also want to use an inneficient allocator that just alocated a `Vec`, which lives by itself. That's why I wanted the `Box` to contain anything that implement `AsRef<[T]>`, not just return a slice. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: in summary: I want to return a Box of something that implements `AsRef`, but this something could be a slice (short lifetime) or a vec (static lifetime). The second case is for when I need to pass things to other threads, etc

Comment: Well you can implement your own trait similar to `AsRef` [like so](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e549b30d9e9d17462e0740b28a61dff1). But I feel that won't help your intentions, because even if you return a owned `Vec`, its hidden behind that trait object and will still be bound to that `'r` lifetime just like a slice.

Comment: yes but the times I need to return a `Vec` would be the times where the stuff is compiled with `'r = 'static`. I truly don't need it to be chosen on runtime. I like implementing my own `AsRef` but then it wouldn't work automatically where `AsRef` is needed, which is kind of boring :c

Comment: I'm trying to implement `DataRef` from your example, for a Vec, but it looks impossible without `'a` in `&self`, but if I do that then I get a lot of trouble in other stuff